# Passing strings as pointer to a function

Tags: c, string, function, pointers

It's a simple function for many but as a beginner, I've yet to overcome the pointer ghost specially when it comes to strings. I understand some of the examples of strcmp, strcpy, strlen as well as how the characters are assigned in the memory with a NULL terminator.  I think I also get the point how a pointer variable in memory points to the address of a int var or char etc. and you assign them by dereferencing them to var/char, but whenever I try to write a code, the pointer ghost comes back to bite me. 
So, here I'm trying to run this and doesn't work. I would appreciate if you could clarify this for me...

```
//GETNAME function should return a string that is not NULL and less than 20 characters

char getname (char *s1)
{
int i, n;
char s2[i];
printf ("Enter your name:" );
scanf ("%s", "s2");

if (s2 == NULL)
    return 0;

else if(n<20)

for ( i=0, n =strlen (s2 + 1); i<n; i++)

*(s1+i) = s2[i]; //copy characters from s2 and point to chars of s1

return *s1; 
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])   

{       
    char name[20];
    char urname;

    urname = getname(name);

    printf (" Your name is : %s\n", urname);

    getch();

return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". We have no idea what this is supposed to do, and we can't be forced to debug the code for you.

Comment: It looks like you want `scanf ("%s", s2);` instead of `scanf ("%s", "s2");`

Comment: Here I'm trying to print name input from the main function as long as it's not larger than 20 characters or null. It's a mess I know, but trying to clarify what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 3):

Here are several errors; there may be more:

1. Uninitialized variable:

   ```
   int i, n;
   char s2[i];
   ```

   `i` is not initialized here, yet you use it as if it was. What value should `i` have? Like this it is undefined behaviour.
2. Incorrect argument to `scanf`:

   ```
   scanf ("%s", "s2");
   ```

   The second parameter should be a pointer to the memory that you want the input to be written to, not a constant string. It should be:

   ```
   scanf ("%s", s2);
   ```
3. Incorrect argument to `strlen`:

   ```
   for ( i=0, n =strlen (s2 + 1); i<n; i++)
   ```

   You want to add `1` to the string length not to the string itself, so it should be

   ```
   for ( i=0, n = strlen(s2) + 1; i<n; i++)
   ```
4. General issues with `getname`, including return type:

   ```
   char getname (char *s1)
   ```

   Why is this function so complex? You could directly `scanf` into the parameter `s1`. You don't need `s2` for anything. Also the return type is wrong. You return a pointer, not a single `char`. It should be:

   ```
   char* getname(char *s1)
   ```
5. Not handling return value from `getname` properly:

   ```
   char urname;
   urname = getname(name);
   ```

   `getname` returns a pointer to char, not a single char. It should be:

   ```
   char* urname;
   urname = getname(name);
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your great reply; I'm trying to learn this myself and I see I'm lacking some fundamentals... I guess I need to study more basics and do some problem solving before writing functions. Truly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

As the previous post says that `i` is not initialised.

Also the line

```
scanf("%s", "s2");
```

Should be

```
scanf("%s", s2);
```

The lines

```
if (s2 == NULL)
    return 0;

else if(n<20)
```

Is incorrect as `s2` will not be NULL and `n` is not initialised

... That is for starters

I recommend you get a book and read it

Comment: Thanx! buying a book right now...